# Is it possible to implement a frozen header?

Tags: feature-request

The new top-bar for Aviation Stack-Exchange is much better than the old one, in my opinion. But I think it can be improved by making it stick to the top of the view-port, for enabling easy access to notifications. Right now, we have to scroll to the top, to even see if we have any notifications.

A "Back to Top" Button can also be created, but the former seems more straight-forward.

Comment: This is [in review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301845/151305) right now.

Comment: Thank you - as I mentioned in the OP, the frozen header would be better than a back-to-top button, IMHO.

Comment: If the feature will not be added officially and I've got time, I can write a small chrome extension for you to download, that makes the top-bar sticky.

Comment: That's very kind of you - but it isn't a personal request at all really - a simple work-around is to just use the 'Home' key to go to the top of the page. No -
 it's not just for me - it's for the whole community. But your helping-tendency is much appreciated - thank you! : )

Comment: @AnandS Just finished the extension and works on all SE-Sites. Unfortunately, there is a 5$ payment required to publish it in the chrome store. But that's no problem, as I always wanted to have a dev-account for chrome-extensions. I will notify you as soon as I published it.

Comment: @NoahKrasser Wow! That was quick! Thank you for your sincere efforts! As a side-note, _is it possible to implement the sticky bar within the SE network itself? Can you collab with the devs?_

Comment: @AnandS I am unfortunately not in contact with the devs and it's also not much work to make the top-bar sticky. It's actually only one line of code. I guess they tested both variants, sticky and static and took the one more liked, of course not representing every SE-user. But they should really implement a setting to toggle stickiness of the top-bar, according to one's needs.